# Received PIP after resignation

Tags: human-resources

I resigned my current position to work for another segment of my company. The company is so big that I have to resign then get rehired in the different segment.

Halfway through my resignation period my manager hit me with a PIP (performance improvement plan). None of the items listed were ever discussed either verbally or email.  I refused to recognize the PIP and accelerated my last day.

The next day the manager called to tell me I was under investigation for downloading company software to USB. He stated that he wanted it back and would forget about it if I just admitted it. I never downloaded any software let alone put on USB against company policy. I believe this is all an attempt to derail and sabotage my move to the new segment were it would shift the balance of power.

**What's a good approach to ensuring a smooth transition between organizational units of the same company when the sending unit is clearly attempting to sabotage the move?**

Comment: If you want an answer to the question "can I sue", you need to talk to a lawyer in your local area who specialises in that kind of thing. Us random folk on the internet cannot answer that question for you.

Comment: This doesn't just sound like retaliation, it sounds like blackmail or emotional manipulation. Before you jump to a lawsuit, make a written record of everything, ask him for his statements in writing (under the guise of "to make sure I understand what you're asking") and find out what your next steps are to protect yourself. Your new management may be able to assist you, or you may have an anonymous governance/ethics hotline you can call to ask about it.

Comment: Get a lawyer this guys trying to get you

Comment: And document everything in diary

Comment: Document everything offsite, talk to a lawyer if this can constitute harassment or even sabotage / entrapment. Perhaps, when move is complete, mention to new manager that previous one does strange things that looks like he is trying to ruin you

Comment: Do you already know your new manager? Maybe talk to him/her as well about the situation.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I removed anything regarding lawsuit. I have never heard of a PIP used in this manner. Seems the offending manager missed used its intended purpose.

Comment: *He stated that he ... would forget about it if I just admitted it.* - This is what people say when they've got no proof, no witness, no testimony, nothin'.

Comment: I'd install an automatic call recorder on my cellphone at once, in case this guy calls you instead of mailing you. And test the call recorder, especially with incoming calls - some don't work well on all phones. (This is assuming call recording is legal where you live, recording your own calls is legal where I live.)

Comment: You should spell out what "PIP" means the first time you use it so folks won't need to Google it (like I did).

Comment: `performance improvement plan` had to google, too.

Comment: Had to resign sounds very strange is this transferring between countries ? corporate entities also which country is this

Comment: "He wanted it back" is an odd thing to say about what would presumably be a *copy* of things. Does he realize that copying a file doesn't destroy the original? It sounds like he's been watching too many movies and is using a Hollywood scenario to try to manipulate you into something questionable.

Comment: have you discussed any of this with the head of your new department? Chances are you current boss is. Hopefully, the head of your new department will recognize this for what it is.

Comment: Such a big company might have an ombundsman, which might help with exactly such kinds of issues

Answer (score 31):

> Halfway through my resignation period my manager hit me with a PIP.

This is a red flag in any case, and highly unusual. Not much point in improving the performance of an employee when they are already leaving. Unless you have an unusual notice period when they want to cut it down unethically using clauses of PIP. Or if the manager is trying to sabotage your career record (Employee X got a PIP is on the record for you)

> I refused to recognize the PIP and accelerated my last day

Is the HR aware of any of the above steps so far? If not, they need to be involved.

> He then called me to tell me I was under investigation for downloading company software to USB.

This is a very pointed and highly serious charge. The type of charge that is cause for being fired at most places, and gets mentioned in your work records because it would fall into category of [espionage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_espionage). Think it through completely - did anyone else use your system for downloading such a thing? May be you forgot to lock your screen? Be sure that you are on the right side before proceeding further. Be doubly sure this is not a trap - you later mention change in balance of power, could there have been motivated physical sabotage involving your account? Are you being set up?

> He would forget about it if I just admitted it.

Once you admit, his current feelings that he states do not matter, he/the company has evidence you are guilty. This is him making you shoot your own hand. Check with a lawyer before replying in any manner.

> This is all an attempt to derail and sabotage my move to the new segment where it would shift the balance of power. Do I have a case for a lawsuit?

Based on your description so far, this seems correct. But only a lawyer can answer if this is a lawsuit case or not based on your jurisdiction. Your manager has definitely been harassing you, but only a lawyer can tell which laws he has broken.

So far, mental trauma, defamation (if investigation is leaked) come to mind.

**TLDR: If I was in your shoes, I would immediately run to a good lawyer.**

Comment: Talking to the new department head might also be helpful?

Comment: @Mawg The original question was edited before being reopened, I haven't updated my answer to reflect that.